# is cacheitemremovedcallback of HttpRuntime.Cache thread safe?

Tags: .net, thread-safety, httpruntime.cache

i use HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert to insert data into cache.
i have the function 'onremove' as the cacheitemremovedcallback - when the cache expires (after 15 minutes) it releases data in cache and calls 'onremove' that insert the data again to the cache.

everytime i want to use the data in the cache i check that the data is there first:

```
if (HttpRuntime.Cache[CACHE_DATA_TABLE] == null)
            { // load data into cache again}
```

what happens if i check that the data is in the cache and it is there, but as soon as i want to use it it expires? 
so when i call:

```
DATADT = (DataTable)HttpRuntime.Cache[CACHE_DATA_TABLE]
```

Does the HttpRuntime.Cache waits untill 'onremove' is called and finish loading the data back into cache before it extract the data ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [CacheItemUpdateCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemupdatecallback.aspx) delegate instead.

This lets you take the desired action *before* the item is about to be removed.

See:
[MSDN on Cache.Insert Method (String, Object, CacheDependency, DateTime, TimeSpan, CacheItemUpdateCallback)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491414.aspx)